# wait_for 'reaction_add' check doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm doing a command where you need to confirm something with emojis.
I have a `wait_for("reaction_add")` with a check as a lambda function.

The following code I have is:

```
try:
    reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add",
    check=lambda react, usr: str(reaction.emoji) == "✅" and usr.id == ctx.author.id, timeout=60)
    print(reaction.emoji)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await confirm_msg.edit(content="This message has timed out!", embed=None)
```

But it doesn't print out the reaction emoji.
Without the check the code works fine, so it has to do with the check. How could I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```py
try:
    reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add",
    check=lambda reaction, user: str(reaction.emoji) == "✅" and user.id == ctx.author.id, timeout=60)
    print(reaction.emoji)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await confirm_msg.edit(content="This message has timed out!", embed=None)
```

Comment: `lambda reaction, user`**

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszKwieciński

Answer (score 1):

A **lambda** function is esentially the same as a normal function.

Your lambda:

```
lambda react, usr: str(reaction.emoji) == "✅" and usr.id == ctx.author.id
```

Would be equal to defining the following function:

```
# Here we are within the wait_for(reaction_add)
def f(react, usr):
    return str(reaction.emoji) == "✅" and user.id == ctx.author.id
# Rest of the code
```

The problem is that the `reaction_add` does not have `react` or `usr` defined. The way to solve your code would be something like this:

```
reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction,
user: str(reaction.emoji) == "✅" and user.id == ctx.author.id, timeout=60)
```

Comment: "The problem is that the `reaction_add` does not have `react` or `usr` defined". It doesn't have to do with `reaction_add` so much as it does with the wrong name being used *within the lambda expression*. Modifying the condition to use `str(react.emoji)` would have worked as well.

Comment: Hey, this still doesn't work for me. Should I send guys you the full command, maybe there's something wrong elsewhere? I doubt it but it's worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, without the lambda function:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  reaction = str(payload.emoji)
  if reaction == "✅" and usr.id == ctx.author.id:
     print('do something')
  else:
     print('something else')
```

Comment: this unfortunately won't be the solution for me as i need to check something against a variable above the code snippet i posted

Comment: and also the ctx variable isnt there anymore